# How do I use update_attributes with custom setter methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes

I have a model called `Contact` with an attribute called `phone_number`.  I have some custom setter methods such as

```
def prefix=(num)  
  self.phone_number[3..5] = num  
end
```

When I call `@contact.update_attributes({:prefix => '510'})`, I don't get any errors and `@contact` gets changed, but the changes don't make their way to the database.  I've tried using `attr_accessible` to specifically allow using these setter methods to no avail.

Is there any way to get `update_attributes` to work for me?  I'm using Rails 2.3.8.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to inform rails that you have changed an attribute as you are performing in place modifications:

```
def prefix=(num)
  phone_number_will_change!
  self.phone_number[3..5] = num
end
```

Comment: Bah!  That gets me every time.  Thanks, Kandada.

Comment: The `phone_number_will_change!` is not needed if you call `super num` at the end of the method.

Comment: @Hendrik here we are trying to update the string in place. So it doesn't go through the AR dirty infra. The actual attribute is `phone_number` but you are updating the prefix. There is no `super` for `prefix` as it is not a DB attribute. Look at the AR Dirty documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html